# OS X 10.9.4 - How can I limit the number of failed login attempts?

Tags: macos, security, login

With OS X 10.9.4, how can I limit the number of failed local login attempts?

I'm looking for something similar to the Windows Account Lockout Threshold mentioned here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994574.aspx

Comment: There is no built in mechanism to lock an account on OS X. You'll need either a directory service or to add on some software. I've edited that separate question out of this to leave the how to implement a similar feature to stand on it's own.

Answer (score 1):

If you use OS X Server (which is pretty cheap these days) you can change the global password policy.   http://www.wikihow.com/Image:ServerAppUsrsGrps8.png